# using the CreateProcess function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create something similar to a cmd with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop in c++ and one of my function should start a process like open skype by typing "skype.exe". I searched in the internet and found the CreateProcess function that should do the work for me. when I created a function that receives a class value that I created called Line (the name of the class but it doesn't really metter) and used the CreateProcess function in the way that is shown bellow I have to type in my cmd "start skype.exe" but I want it to work like in the regular cmd by writing only "skype.exe", how can I do it? 
(the l.parameter is just a string that contains the word skype)

```
void execute(Line l){

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
LPSTR s = const_cast<char *>(l.parameter.c_str());
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, s, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing is that:

```
LPSTR s = const_cast<char *>(l.parameter.c_str());
```

is bad idea, [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) accepts for `lpCommandLine` non const buffer for a reason - it might modify it:

> The system adds a terminating null character to the command-line string to separate the file name from the arguments. This divides the original string into two strings for internal processing.

so you should pass an array, for example:

```
TCHAR szCmd[MAX_PATH] = {0};
```

then to your question, if "start skype.exe" works for you and you want to enter only skype.exe at the command line - then why not concatenate strings? for example:

```
_tcscat(szCmd, _T("start "));
_tcscat(szCmd, parameter.c_str());
```

and pass szCmd to CreateProcess

the question is whether you use UNICODE build, if yes then make sure parameter is std::wstring, otherwise if you use non-UNICODE build (and it looks like thats true) then std::string is fine.

Comment: Since the code is compiling with `LPSTR`, then `UNICODE` is clearly not defined, and the Ansi version of `CreateProcess()` does not modify the command buffer, only the Unicode version does.  Also, running `start` as the command will not work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`start` is not an executable, it is a feature of `cmd.exe`, so to invoke `start skype.exe` via `CreateProcess()`, you would have to specify `cmd.exe` as the command and `/C start skype.exe` as its parameter.

```
Line l;
line.parameter = "cmd.exe /C start skype.exe";
execute(l);
```

But that is overkill in this situation, as `start` is not actually needed, despite what you claim. It is perfectly valid and preferable to invoke `skype.exe` directly as the command.

However, you have to provide the *full path* to `skype.exe` (same if you were to invoke `start`), otherwise `CreateProcess()` won't be able to find it, as Skype does not register its .exe file path in the `App Paths` key of the Registry, or the path to its `Phone` subfolder (where `skype.exe` resides) on the system's `%PATH%` environment variable.

For example:

```
Line l;
line.parameter = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype.exe";
execute(l);
```

Fortunately, Skype does store the full path to `skype.exe` in the Registry, specifically in the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Skype\Phone
```

It is stored in a `REG_SZ` value named `"SkypePath"`.

```
std::string GetSkypePath()
{
    std::string sPath;

    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Skype\\Phone", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == 0)
    { 
        char szPath[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
        DWORD dwPathLen = MAX_PATH;

        if (RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "SkypePath", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szPath, &dwPathLen) == 0)
            sPath = szPath;            

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return sPath;
}
```